# ActiveSupport::Dependencies#load() Overrides `load` Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

...in a bizarrely consistent way too.

I have a few models with a `load` attribute. When I pop open an console session or `reload!` the universe I consistently see the same `ArgumentError` on any `load` call until I call ***anything else*** on any other model instance with a `load` attribute:

```
Work.new.load
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
# from gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:220:in `load'
Butt.new.load
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
# from gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:220:in `load'
Work.new.class  # or even Work.new.nonexistant_method
# => Work
Work.new.load
# => nil
Butt.new.load
# => nil
```

I fixed the problem with this ridiculous hack:

```
after_initialize :fix_load_nonsense
def fix_load_nonsense; end
```

Comment: You didn't show your model code, but `load` is, if I am not mistaken, a method that rails defines on an active-record model.  It may be that you should not name an attribute `load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#load` is a method from Ruby's [Kernel Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html). Since `Kernel` is included by the class `Object`, the `#load` method is available in every Ruby object. Overwriting it is potentially dangerous, so `#load` should not be used as the name for an attribute.

I believe the issue regarding the `ArgumentError` occurs in clean memory spaces is due to the autoloading behaviors of the development console.